how to use targetDefaults in nx.json correctly
Feel like I am missing something, but I thought targetDefault in NX18 should be able to pass options to project level. However, I can't get it to work with nx-dotnet.
The goal is trying to run nx-dotnet format with options from lint in nx.json. However, it can't get the options. But if I set options in project.json, it works.
Here is the github repo https://github.com/Sam-Lin-MillersLab/nx-dotnet-test
nx.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/nx/schemas/nx-schema.json",
  "defaultBase": "main",
  "targetDefaults": {
    "build": {
      "cache": true,
      "dependsOn": ["^build"]
    },
    "lint": {
      "cache": true,
      "options": {
        "fix": true,
        "fixWhitespace": true,
        "fixStyle": "warn",
        "fixAnalyzers": "warn",
        "report": "./.reports",
        "verbosity": "diagnostic"
      }
    }
  },
  "plugins": ["@nx-dotnet/core"]
}

I also tried the following settings, that doesn't work either
"@nx-dotnet/core:format": {
      "cache": true,
      "options": {
        "fix": true,
        "fixWhitespace": true,
        "fixStyle": "warn",
        "fixAnalyzers": "warn",
        "report": "./.reports",
        "verbosity": "diagnostic"
      }
    }

